# How does this definition of a topology on $X$ not cause $X \in X$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

From Wikipedia:

Formally, let X be a set and let $\tau$ be a family of subsets of X. Then $\tau$ is called a topology on X if:

1. Both the empty set and X are elements of $\tau$.
2. Any union of elements of τ is an element of $\tau$.
3. Any intersection of finitely many elements of τ is an element of $\tau$.

I'm confused about (1). If $\tau$ is a family of subsets of X, and X is a member/element of $\tau$  then doesn't that suggest that X is a member of itself, which generally speaking isn't allowed?

Comment: $X$ is a subset of itself, so can be a element of a family (i.e. set) of subsets of $X$

Answer (score 14):

"then doesn't that suggest that X is a member of itself” No, it suggests $X$ is a **subset** of itself, because $\tau$ is a family of **subsets** of $X$.

Answer (score 11):

Careful. A topology is a *subcollection* of $2^X$, the power set of $X$. So if say $X = \{a,b\}$, maybe $\tau = \{\varnothing, \{a\}, \{b\}, X\}$.  Thus $X \in \tau$, but this says nothing about $X \in X$, which would, you're right, be problematic.  In other words, a collection of subsets of $X$, such as $\tau$, is a different 'kind' of object than $X$ itself.

Comment: I'd not seen the notation $2^X$ for the power set of $X$ before; especially if the OP is relatively new to thinking about set theory and topologies it might be a bit obstructive compared to something like $\mathcal{P}(X)$. If one is already learning to keep track of a set, its subsets and its elements, putting a notation based around functions into the mix is quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[Other](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4514820/2439) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4514817/2439) already describe the general situation well, but a concrete example may also help.

Think about the real numbers, $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\R$.  Certainly this isn’t an element of itself — $\R$ is not a real number.  The standard topology on it is given by $\tau_\R := \{ U \subseteq \R \mid \forall x \in U,\, \exists \epsilon > 0,\ B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq U\}$ — the collection of all open sets of reals (in the standard metric definition of “open”).

Now the biggest subset possible subset of $\R$ is *all* the reals, i.e. $\R$ itself, and it’s certainly open.  So $\R \in \tau_\R$.  And generally this is what the axiom says: **In any topological space, the whole space (viewed as a subset of itself) is open.**